# Extract url from a string with regex in shell script

Tags: regex, shell, busybox

I need to extract a URL that is wrapped with `<strong>` tags. It's a simple regular expression, but I don't know how to do that in shell script. Here is example:

```
line="<strong>http://www.example.com/index.php</strong>"
url=$(echo $line | sed -n '/strong>(http:\/\/.+)<\/strong/p')
```

I need "http://www.example.com/index.php" in the `$url` variable.

Using busybox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
url=$(echo $line | sed -n 's!<strong>\(http://[^<]*\)</strong>!\1!p')
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work:

```
url=$(echo $line | sed -r 's/<strong>([^<]+)<\/strong>/\1/')
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to escape forward slashes with backslashes. Only backslashes need to be escaped in regular expressions. You should also use non-greedy matching with the `?`-operator to avoid getting more than you want when there are multiple strong tags in the HTML sourcecode.

```
strong>(http://.+?)</strong
```

Answer (score 0):

Update: as `busybox` uses `ash`, the solution assuming `bash` features likely won't work. Something only a little longer but still POSIX-compliant will work:

```
url=${line#<strong>}  # $line minus the initial "<strong>"
url=${url%</strong>}  # Remove the trailing "</strong>"
```

---

If you are using `bash` (or another shell with similar features), you can combine extended pattern matching with parameter substitution. (I don't know what features busybox supports.)

```
# Turn on extended pattern support
shopt -s extglob

# ?(\/) matches an optional forward slash; like /? in a regex
# Expand $line, but remove all occurrances of <strong> or </strong>
# from the expansion
url=${line//<?(\/)strong>}
```